# NSWindow won't accept drag and dropped files

Tags: cocoa

I'm trying to get a window I've created to accept files dropped onto it from the finder and all that happens when I try and drag a file onto the window is it snaps back to where it was on the desktop.  Clearly I'm not setting something up right.

Inside the `NSWindowController:initWithWindow:` I'm doing:

```
    [self.window registerForDraggedTypes:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:NSFilenamesPboardType, nil]];
```

I've tried putting this line in the view as well and no luck.  What am I missing?  Is there something I need to set in the .xib file as well?

Where do I need to put the `-(BOOL)performDragOperation:` function?  Is that in my custom NSWindowController class?  Is that what is failing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you followed (or read) the [documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/DragandDrop/Tasks/acceptingdrags.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000993-BABHHIHC)? The relevant section is titled "Receiving Drag Operations.

Most importantly, for a general view (or window), you need to implement -draggingEntered: as a first step and return the proper NSDragOperation (or at least not NSDragOperationNone) to "validate" the proposed drop. Without answering this, a drop won't even be allowed (so you'll never receive -prepareForDragOperation:, -performDragOperation: or -concludeDragOperation:).

Something else to consider: Do you really want the whole window to act as the dragging destination? More often, it's best to use a specific view that gives visual feedback to the user when -draggingUpdated: is called.

Comment: Yes, I have read the documentation. I would not have posted here had I not.  I did not glean that it was required to implement this function and sample code I looked at does not. I will try this.

Comment: With respect, *plenty* of people post on sites like this without reading the documentation. Also, you missed the last part of the "Dragging Destinations" page (the very last thing before the section I linked) that specifically states "The six NSDraggingDestination methods are invoked in a distinct order:" and, as the first in that order: "As the image is dragged into the destination’s boundaries, the destination is sent a draggingEntered: message. The method should return a value that indicates which dragging operation the destination will perform."

Comment: Thank you this works like a charm now. I was looking at completely different docs than this on drag-and-drop. I don't know why there would be two unless google is just linking to old stuff.  Thanks for the correct link.